# Log the logon Windows just one time for the day

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I did a script which log everyone when users log in TSE (Windows Server 2008 R2). The script lauches with a GPO.

`echo %date%;%time:~0,8%;%username% >> D:\log\log.txt`

I want to log users the first time of the day.
E.g :
user1 log at 9:35 9:38 12:30 18:38 just one line in the log :

```
26/06/2017;09:35:00;user1
```

Comment: A related command would be: `wmic netlogin get name, fullname, lastlogon`. This would also eliminate the problem of regional settings impacting the date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in ('findstr /b /c:"%date%;" "D:\log\log.txt" 2^>nul^|findstr /c:";%username%" 2^>nul') do goto nolog
echo %date%;%time:~0,8%;%username% >> D:\log\log.txt 
:nolog
```

Find any lines that start with `date;`, and find any of those that end `;username`. If any hits (ie user has already logged in today) then `goto` over the login recording. If none, execute the following line and record the new logon.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but here is a way to do it that eliminates the regional settings date format problem and ensures that it is always the format you specify.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "$(get-date -Format 'MM\/dd\/yyyy') + ';' + $(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss) + ';' + "$Env:USERDOMAIN" + '\' + "$Env:USERNAME"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @lit, I don't use powershell yet but it's a beginning to understand some things